# How to create this kind of XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create via C# code XML like this:

```
<Title>
   <A>
       <aaaaaaaaaaaaa/>
   </A>
   <B>
       <bbbbbbbbbbbbb/>
   </B>
</Title>
```

With what code should i create tree like thist?

Comment: You have several options, from XML serialization to Linq. Please elaborate on your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you can use **LINQ to XML** it's insanely easy:

```
XElement root = new XElement(
    "Title",
    new XElement("A",
        new XElement("aaaaaaaaaaaaa")),
    new XElement("B",
        new XElement("bbbbbbbbbbbbb"))
);
```

Additionally, if you need to build this dynamically from data (which you probably will), you can include the queries within the constructor calls, and it will all work.

LINQ to XML really is an impressively easy-to-use API. Of course, it does require .NET 3.5 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). There is a nice example.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), i.e. the [System.Xml.Linq namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx):

```
var result = new XElement("Title",
                 new XElement("A",
                     new XElement("aaaaaaaaaaaaa")),
                 new XElement("B",
                     new XElement("bbbbbbbbbbbbb")));
```