# Creating Simple Xml In C#

Tags: c#

I need help some help printing out some xml. Here is my code (which isnt working its not even formatting the full url right, it doesnt understand "//" in the url string) It also doesnt understand "<". There must be a better way to do this??

```
 foreach (string url in theUrls)
         {
             fullurl=@"http://www.cambit.com/restaurants" +url;
             xml = xml + @"<url>" + Environment.NewLine +
                       @"<loc>" + fullurl + @"</loc>" + Environment.NewLine +
                       @"<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>" + Environment.NewLine +
                       @"<priority>0.80</priority>" + Environment.NewLine +
                       @"</url>" + Environment.NewLine;    

        }
```

It returns 400 of these appended right next to each other. Environment.NewLine isn't working either....

> http://www.cambit.com/restaurantsBerwyn
>   weekly 0.80

I tried this and it says the loc object is not set to an instance of an object

```
 XmlDocument aNewNode = new XmlDocument();
 XmlElement urlRoot = aNewNode.CreateElement("url");
 //aNewNode.DocumentElement.AppendChild(urlRoot);
 XmlElement loc = aNewNode.CreateElement("loc");
 XmlText locText = aNewNode.CreateTextNode(fullurl);
 aNewNode.DocumentElement.AppendChild(loc);
 aNewNode.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(locText);
 XmlElement chgFreq = aNewNode.CreateElement("changefreq");
 XmlText chgFreqText = aNewNode.CreateTextNode("weekly");
 aNewNode.DocumentElement.AppendChild(chgFreq);
 aNewNode.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(chgFreqText);
 XmlElement priority = aNewNode.CreateElement("priority");
 XmlText priorityText = aNewNode.CreateTextNode("0.80");
 aNewNode.DocumentElement.AppendChild(priority);
 aNewNode.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(priorityText);
```

What am doing wrong??

Comment: When you say "printing" do you mean writing it to a printer, outputting to a webpage or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042813/how-to-create-this-kind-of-xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to use XDocument, which has [lots of documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). Here's an example from the documentation:

```
XDocument srcTree = new XDocument(
    new XComment("This is a comment"),
    new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
        new XElement("Child2", "data2"),
        new XElement("Child3", "data3"),
        new XElement("Child2", "data4"),
        new XElement("Info5", "info5"),
        new XElement("Info6", "info6"),
        new XElement("Info7", "info7"),
        new XElement("Info8", "info8")
    )
);

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XComment("This is a comment"),
    new XElement("Root",
        from el in srcTree.Element("Root").Elements()
        where ((string)el).StartsWith("data")
        select el
    )
);

Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

The way this would work for your example would be something like:

```
public XDocument CreateDocument(IEnumerable<string> theUrls)
{
    var urlElements = theUrls.Select(u => CreateUrlElement(u));
    return new XDocument(new XElement("Urls", urlElements));
}

public XElement CreateUrlElement(string url)
{
    return new XElement("Url",
        new XElement("loc", fullUrl),
        ... the rest of your elements ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). There is a nice example on that website.

Answer (score 0):

you probably should use CDATA section

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: i thought url part might corrupt xml and interpreted as corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLWriter class, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  is example. Or maybe better [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)